# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap

Tags: java, excel, apache

Trying to create a class that writes to an Excel file.

Error(https://gyazo.com/8d8977786add756057bb1d32866942df): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap

Libaries I have added (https://gyazo.com/cfa1555bd58de436bc243f1067b9e08b):
poi-3.16.jar,
poi-ooxml-3.16.jar,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar,
commons-collections4-4.0.jar,
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

```
public void Create(){
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(("Results"));



    try {
        FileOutputStream stream= new FileOutputStream(filelocation);
        workbook.write(stream);
        workbook.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did you include the necessary import statements for the libraries/packages you are using or did you just not include them in this post?

Comment: i added the imports just not in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a more recent version of commons-collections4.
If you look at the Javadocs for [`ListValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap.html), you'll see that it was introduced in version 4.1, and you have 4.0 on your classpath.

You should consider using Maven or another dependency management tool as it will save you a lot of headaches.